# How do I properly search for a value inside a 4 by 4 2d matrix?

Tags: c++, search, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write code that will search a 4 by 4 matrix called matrix[4][4].
Users will be able to type their own values in. At the end it questions the user what value does the user wish to search for. The code I have written will display the wrong message. For example, even if the matrix has a 22 in it the program will say that the matrix does not contain 22. This is the loop that searches the matrix.

```
int result;
cout << "Which value would you like to search for in the matrix?: ";
cin >> result;

int search = 0;
for (search = 0; search < 4; search++)
{
    for (int value = 0; value < 4; value++)
    {
        if (matrix[search][value] == result)
        {
            cout << "Your matrix contains " << result << endl;
            return search; 
        }

        else

            cout << "Your matrix does not contain " << result << endl;
            return 0;       

    }
}
```

I want the program to display the right output. If user searches for a 30 and the matrix contains a 30, it should not say that the matrix does not contain a 30.

Comment: You need to remember the Golden Rule of Computer Programming: your computer will always do exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do. You told your computer: start searching the matrix starting at cell(0,0). If that cell contains the `result`, print a message that the result is found. Otherwise (if that cell, cell(0,0) does not contain the result), print a message that the result is not found, and return. And that's exactly what your computer is doing, as per your instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You should reply that the value is not found only after searching all of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

As Sam Varshavchik said, on the first iteration of the inner loop, it checks to see whether the first element is what is being searched for, or else it tells you that the element was not found, without checking any other value since it then returns 0.

Since you usually don't have the element you're looking for on the first element, you should only say that the value has not been found once the outer loop finishes, and we know that if the loops didn't return anything, then the code will arrive at the section where it tells the user that the element was not found.

So, the loop would look like this:

```
int search = 0;
for (search = 0; search < 4; search++)
{
    for (int value = 0; value < 4; value++)
    {
        if (matrix[search][value] == result)
        {
            cout << "Your matrix contains " << result << endl;
            return search; 
        } 
    }
}

//If the program gets here, it has checked all elements
cout << "Your matrix does not contain " << result << endl;
return 0;
```